# Protect Workbook from xlam Add-ins

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with some password-protected VBA code. Through this code some sheets are hidden (status=xlsVeryHidden).

But if I load an .xlam Add-in module, I can turn the sheets to Visible again (looping for each worksheet, changing the status).

Is there a way to prevent any .xlam add-in from being installed on a specific workbook (the workbook will be shared to other users at a later stage) ?

Or is there something "stronger" than xlsVeryHidden (so that it cannot be reversed) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can protect yourself with:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Protect "Password ", True
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

`Is there a way to prevent any .xlam add-in from being installed on a specific workbook`

The Add-Ins are not installed on a specific workbook. They are installed on your Excel Application :)

If your Add-In is making your worksheets visible that is because there must be some code in the Add-In which is making it visible.

`Or is there something "stronger" than xlsVeryHidden (so that it cannot be reversed) ?`

No.

BTW `ADDIN` or `NO ADDIN`, You can loop through the sheets and make them visible. The only way to protect the sheets from being visible is to **Protect your workbook**(*different than protecting the workshee*t) after you hide your worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

If you `Protect` the `Structure` of your workbook with a password after you hide the sheet, then code from another workbook or add-in will not be able to "unhide" it unless the turn off protection first using that password.